# Where are the OpenCV libraries?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu and downloaded OpenCV and Eclipse and when i try to configure OpenCV libraries to get rid of `undefined reference to XXX` I find that `opencv-2.4.31\build\lib` folder is empty !

I found many question that talk about this problem but the answer was to use a command like that

```
g++ -o appname appname.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

And that's not what I'm looking for, I need to link the libraries with eclipse.

Comment: Easier to just use cmake and let it worry about this

Comment: A google search with "ubuntu opencv" gave me [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV). Do try installing the library instead of keeping a directory with non-built sources.

Comment: @Bull The tutorial i followed to install opencv uses cmake but the lib folder still empty

Comment: @E_net4 I don't know what do you mean with `Do try installing the library instead of keeping a directory with non-built sources` But the link you provided uses the command that i mentioned

Comment: Perhaps you don't know what `pkg-config --cflags opencv` and `pkg-config --libs opencv` means. Try running these commands in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

the libraries you're looking for should be in the /usr/include/opencv... directory. If there was some issue during initial openCV config, you might find them in /usr/local/include/opencv... directory, in which case you'd need to copy them to the former